# Why does adding a string state variable cause out of gas error?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-deployment, javascript

So when I try to add two (or even just the one) state string variables to the Boostr contract (title & description) I get the following error

> There was a problem deploying the contract: Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas limit.

But by removing them the contract deploys no problem.

Boostr.sol (fixed)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

    contract BoostrFactory {
            address[] private deployedBoostrs;

            function createBoostr(uint minimum) public {
                    address newBoostr = new Boostr(minimum, msg.sender);
                    deployedBoostrs.push(newBoostr);
            }

            function getAllBoostrs() public view returns (address[]) {
                    return deployedBoostrs;
            }
    }

    contract Boostr {
            struct Request {
                    string description;
                    uint value;
                    address recipient;
                    bool complete;
                    mapping(address=>bool) approval;
                    uint approvalCount;
            }

            Request[] public requests;
            address private manager;
            uint public minimumContribution;
            mapping(address=>bool) private supporters;
            mapping(address=>bool) private approvers;
            uint public approversCount;

            modifier managerRestricted() {
                    require(msg.sender == manager);
                    _;
            }

            modifier approverRestricted() {
                    require(approvers[msg.sender]);
                    _;
            }

            constructor(uint minimum, address creator) public {
                    manager = creator;
                    minimumContribution = minimum;
            }

            function getManager() public view returns (address) {
                    return manager;
            }

            function getApprover(address addr) public view returns (bool) {
                    return approvers[addr];
            }

            function getSupporter(address addr) public view returns (bool) {
                    return supporters[addr];
            }

            function contribute() public payable {
                    if (msg.value > 0) {
                            supporters[msg.sender] = true;
                            if (msg.value > minimumContribution) {
                                    approvers[msg.sender] = true;
                                    approversCount++;
                            }
                    }
            }

            function getSummary() public view returns (uint, uint, uint, uint, address) {
                    return (
                            minimumContribution,
                            address(this).balance,
                            requests.length,
                            approversCount,
                            getManager()
                    );
            }

            function getRequestsCount() public view returns (uint) {
                    return requests.length;
            }

            function createRequest(string description, uint value, address recipient) public managerRestricted {
                    Request memory newRequest = Request ({
                            description: description,
                            value: value,
                            recipient: recipient,
                            complete: false,
                            approvalCount: 0
                    });
                    requests.push(newRequest);
            }

            function approveRequest(uint index) public {
                    Request storage request = requests[index];
                    require (approvers[msg.sender]);
                    require (!request.approval[msg.sender]);
                    request.approval[msg.sender] = true;
                    request.approvalCount++;
            }

            function finalizeRequest(uint index) public managerRestricted payable {
                    Request storage request = requests[index];
                    require (!request.complete);
                    require (request.approvalCount > approversCount / 2);
                    request.complete = true;
                    request.recipient.transfer(request.value);
            }
    }
```

Boostr.sol (broken)

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

    contract BoostrFactory {
            address[] private deployedBoostrs;

            function createBoostr(string title, string description, uint minimum) public {
                    address newBoostr = new Boostr(title, description, minimum, msg.sender);
                    deployedBoostrs.push(newBoostr);
            }

            function getAllBoostrs() public view returns (address[]) {
                    return deployedBoostrs;
            }
    }

    contract Boostr {
            struct Request {
                    string description;
                    uint value;
                    address recipient;
                    bool complete;
                    mapping(address=>bool) approval;
                    uint approvalCount;
            }

            Request[] public requests;
            address private manager;
            string public title;
            string public description;
            uint public minimumContribution;
            mapping(address=>bool) private supporters;
            mapping(address=>bool) private approvers;
            uint public approversCount;

            modifier managerRestricted() {
                    require(msg.sender == manager);
                    _;
            }

            modifier approverRestricted() {
                    require(approvers[msg.sender]);
                    _;
            }

            constructor(string bstrTitle, string bstrDesription, uint minimum, address creator) public {
                    title = bstrTitle;
                    description = bstrDesription;
                    manager = creator;
                    minimumContribution = minimum;
            }

            function getManager() public view returns (address) {
                    return manager;
            }

            function getApprover(address addr) public view returns (bool) {
                    return approvers[addr];
            }

            function getSupporter(address addr) public view returns (bool) {
                    return supporters[addr];
            }

            function contribute() public payable {
                    if (msg.value > 0) {
                            supporters[msg.sender] = true;
                            if (msg.value > minimumContribution) {
                                    approvers[msg.sender] = true;
                                    approversCount++;
                            }
                    }
            }

            function getSummary() public view returns (string, string, uint, uint, uint, uint, address) {
                    return (
                            title,
                            description,
                            minimumContribution,
                            address(this).balance,
                            requests.length,
                            approversCount,
                            getManager()
                    );
            }

            function getRequestsCount() public view returns (uint) {
                    return requests.length;
            }

            function createRequest(string reqDescription, uint value, address recipient) public managerRestricted {
                    Request memory newRequest = Request ({
                            description: reqDescription,
                            value: value,
                            recipient: recipient,
                            complete: false,
                            approvalCount: 0
                    });
                    requests.push(newRequest);
            }

            function approveRequest(uint index) public {
                    Request storage request = requests[index];
                    require (approvers[msg.sender]);
                    require (!request.approval[msg.sender]);
                    request.approval[msg.sender] = true;
                    request.approvalCount++;
            }

            function finalizeRequest(uint index) public managerRestricted payable {
                    Request storage request = requests[index];
                    require (!request.complete);
                    require (request.approvalCount > approversCount / 2);
                    request.complete = true;
                    request.recipient.transfer(request.value);
            }
    }
```

compile.js

```
    const path = require('path');
    const solc = require('solc');
    const fs = require('fs-extra');

    const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
    const boostrPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Boostr.sol');
    const source = fs.readFileSync(boostrPath, 'utf8');
    const output = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts;

    fs.removeSync(buildPath);

    for (let contract in output) {
        fs.outputJsonSync(
            path.resolve(buildPath, `${contract.replace(':', '')}.json`),
            output[contract]
        );
    }
```

deploy.js

```
    require('../env');
    const path = require('path');
    const fs = require('fs-extra');
    const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
    const Web3 = require('web3');

    const config = require('../config/config');
    const compiledFactory = require('../ethereum/build/BoostrFactory.json');

    const mnemonic = config.mnemonic;
    const network = config.infura.endpoint;

    const provider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, network);
    const web3 = new Web3(provider);

    (async () => {
        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        let factory;
        console.log(`Attempting to deploy from account ${accounts[0]}`);
        try {
            factory = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(compiledFactory.interface))
                .deploy({
                    data: '0x' + compiledFactory.bytecode
                })
                .send({
                    gas: 1000000,
                    from: accounts[0]
                });
            console.log('Contract deployed to:', factory.options.address);
        } catch (err) {
            return console.log('There was a problem deploying the contract:', err);
        }

        const factoryFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'factory.json');
        console.log(factoryFile);
        try {
            await fs.outputFile(
                factoryFile,
                JSON.stringify({ address: factory.options.address })
            );
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(
                `There was a problem generating the address file. You can do this manually by creating ${factoryFile} and saving ${
                    factory.options.address
                } as the content`
            );
        }
    })();
```

package.json

```
    "dependencies": {
        "ajv": "^6.5.3",
        "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
        "fs-extra": "^7.0.0",
        "jsonfile": "^4.0.0",
        "next": "^6.1.1",
        "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
        "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
        "react": "^16.4.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
        "semantic-ui-css": "^2.3.3",
        "semantic-ui-react": "^0.82.3",
        "solc": "^0.4.24",
        "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "0.0.6",
        "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.35"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error message is actually telling you exactly what the problem is (my emphasis):

> There was a problem deploying the contract: Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, **please check your gas limit**.

When I deploy the "broken" version of `BoostrFactory` in Remix, it reports that it used a little over 1.6 million gas (or a little over 1.2 million when compiler optimizations are enabled), but you're setting a gas limit of 1 million gas. Try upping that to at least 1.7 million and see if that takes care of your problem.

Comment: Thanks @smarx. That worked. I had only increased to to 1.5 mil before.